# Java вопрос по кодировкам

Tags: java

Есть у меня клиент и сервер сокет. Пока оба были на винде, вопросов никаких не было, при переносе на Linux появились проблемы с кодировками. Подскажите, где мне нужно указывать кодировку, чтоб и клиент и сервер могли распознавать русские символы, сейчас вместо них знаки вопроса?
Отправка сообщения на сервер, таким образом:

```
  clientSocket = new Socket(ip, port);
            String str = "AUTH:" + "Логин:" + login + ":Пароль:" + pass + ":ENDAUTH" + "\n";

            out = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            out.writeObject(str +"/n");
            out.flush();
            out.reset();
```

Прием сокет сообщения вот такой:

```
     String object;
    
        while ((object = (String) in.readObject()) != null) {
            
            System.out.println("object: " + object);
            if (object != null) {

                String[] result = object.split(":");
                String type = result[0];
```

Изменил приём сообщений, как в гайде

```
  String object;
    
        while ((object = (String) in.readObject()) != null) {
            
            System.out.println("object: " + object);
            if (object != null) {

                String[] result = object.split(":");
                String type = result[0];
             byte[] bytes1 = StringUtils.getBytesUtf8(object);
             
            String utf8EncodedStringApache = StringUtils.newStringUtf8(bytes1);
            System.out.println("utf8EncodedStringApache: " + utf8EncodedStringApache);
```

не поменялась ситуация, так и получаю знаки вопроса вместо слов

Comment: Думаю этот гайд подойдет, это не сложно: https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-encode-utf-8

Comment: @wigravy поменял код, как в ссылке, ничего не изменилось...